# Update Integer Value using Spinner and Submit Button (Android Studio SDK)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, spinner, android-xml

I have been studying Java for Android for a few weeks now and I am working on my first app. Looking thru answers to similar questions on this website, I'm starting to think I'm approaching my problem from the wrong angle. Before I scrap my work, I'd like to ask some questions about my approach. I appreciate your help <3

If I create a **Spinner** from an array in the **strings.xml** file, can I use the value of the spinner (after a **Submit Button** is pressed) to **update an integer** that I have also stored in my strings.xml file, and display it in a **TextView** area?

strings.xml:

```
<integer-array name="numbers_spinner">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</integer-array>

<integer name="my_number">0</integer>
```

activity_myApp.xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/numbers_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/numbers_spinner"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit_button"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@integer/my_number"/>
```

Context: I'm hoping to add the value from the Spinner to a total value, but I haven't worked out how to do that yet. I am currently stuck on creating an event listener to get the value from my Spinner using a Submit Button.

Is it possible to update the value of int my_number in this way, or do I have to create the Spinner Array in the **.java Main Activity file**? I'm happy to do that if necessary, but as I've got it set up this way I'm hoping to continue down this path unless you guys believe it to be a poor choice. I'm grateful for any help you can give, using the strings.xml file OR the MainActivity.java file <3

Comment: The only thing you can't do is update the xml. You will need to keep an `int` within your java class that is incremented when they hit the submit button with the value from the spinner. You can update your TextView with `setText` and use the value of your `int`.

Comment: thanks so much for your explanation, that's exactly what I needed to hear! I'll keep the my_number int in Java, and do the rest in the xml

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using on button click following:

```
textview.setText(String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()));
```

Comment: thanks for your response! As a beginner I'm still a bit baffled by the java side of things, and have written most of my first app using only the xml activity and value files. I'm going to do a bit more research and soon I hope to be able to use the line of code you've given me.